# Remove .class on mobile view

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

**FOUNDATION FRAMEWORK Q:**

Question - is there anyway to remove a .class on an element when site is shown on mobile or tablet device? (i.e. anything below 768px?)

I could easily remove this with a few lines of js. But want my code to be properly formatted. So if there's a way to do it within the foundation framework, I'd prefer to go that route.

Help? I know this is not necessarily a code question..but it sort of is. Hoping someone could enlighten me and point the way - if there is one.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using media queries for this?

Comment: First time using CSS framework. Let me look. I did before...but may not have dug into it fully.

Comment: Media queries have nothing to do with frameworks.  It is simply a feature of CSS.

Comment: Yeah...I know that. First time building for mobile device - while using a css framework. Wasn't looking to re-write CSS code though...so I think I may have asked the wrong question. I was hoping there was something in the framework that could show/hide individual classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a browserdetect script (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) to find out which version and browser you have (i.e. mobile safari) and then use jquery to remove the class from the elements.

However, considering the fact that you are mentioning a class and below 768px I would suggest you to look into the media queries of css: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

EDIT:

turn your logic the other way around and use:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .class {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned, I could easily do this via jQuery. But want to keep it within Foundation Framework.

Comment: Then you're best off using the media queries in css. Removing a class means that your css structure is wrong, you should add a media query that is enabled when you have that class and are over that size.

Comment: I've adapted my answer to demonstrate the use of media queries when you are inverting your logic.

Comment: Thanks...I really was hoping not to re-write CSS. But I guess I have no choice. I just wanted the framework to turn on and off classes based on screen, etc. Doesn't look possible...

Comment: re-writing your css is the best option as the usage of things like javascript can only create problems (browser dependencies) or slow things down. Good luck!